# I need a way to block a certain website from being seen by anything but my lua script

Tags: html, file, url, lua

I need a way of blocking anything but my specific Lua script from accessing a website (the website is plaintext and has Lua code in it) I have run the script without any protection and it works 100%, now I need the website to be inaccessible from anything but the script, how would i do that?

I have already tried using headers but that exposes the header to the script meaning someone can use that header to gain access to the site.

```
RewriteEngine on
SetEnvIf User-Agent .** wget
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=wget
```

above code is in my .htaccess file

I expect that the above code would deny access to the website for everything but mine, but even though my script doesn't send a user-agent it still denies access to the website.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, here: *"I have already tried using headers but that exposes the header to the script"*  Who has access to the script?

Comment: I cannot compile nor obfuscate the script so, everyone.

Comment: How do you intend for the web server to distinguish your script from any other HTTP client? `User-Agent` is an HTTP header too -- it isn't magic. Using it to identify your script is no more secure than using any other header (which is to say, not at all).